# Equivalence of two convergence statements in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

**Question** Let $1\leq p <\infty$ and let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)=1$. Let $g_n\in \mathcal{L}^p$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $g \in \mathcal{L}^p$. Fix $\lambda >0$ and consider the statements (a) and (b) below.

(a)$g_n\rightarrow g$ with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$.

(b)$\mu \left( \left\{x \in X \bigg\vert \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert\geq \lambda  \right\} \right)\rightarrow 0$.

Show that (a) implies (b). Does (b) imply (a)?

**Attempt:** Let $A = \left\{x \in X \bigg\vert \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert\geq \lambda  \right\} $
$$\lVert g_n-g \rVert_p = \left( \int_{X} \vert g_n- g \vert^{p}d\mu \right) ^{1/p}\geq \left( \int_{A} \vert g_n- g \vert^{p}d\mu \right) ^{1/p}\geq \lambda \mu(A)^{1/p} $$
so that
$$ \mu(A)\leq \left( \frac{\lVert g_n -g\rVert_p}{\lambda}\right)^p$$
and right hand side tends to $0$ as $g_n \rightarrow g$ in the $\mathcal{L}^p$ norm. Hence (a) implies (b).

**My Question** Does (b) imply(a)? How can I show it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The converse is not true. [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206804/convergence-in-measure-does-not-imply-l1-convergence)

Comment: Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Counterexamples